# Why do my white icons appear slightly darker in the Android Toolbar?

Tags: android

See the screenshot attached. My "Previous" and "Next" icons, whose color code is #FFFFFF, are somwhat darker than the system icons for "Up" and "Overflow".

This is a problem because it leads some users to assume that the buttons are disabled.

My theme on the AppBarLayout is ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar and on the Toolbar is ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light, in case that matters. I am using appcompat-v7:23.0.1.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the layout XML ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

... and the relevant parts of my Activity code.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        adapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (forms == null) {
            forms = getConfiguredForms();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.uploadButton:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.settingsButton:
                intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Here's the XML for the options menu. They are added by a fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/first_white"
        android:title="@string/first_action"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/previousButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/previous_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/previous_action" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/next_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/next_action" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/lastButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/last_white"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/last_action" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/reset_white"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/reset_action" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you show us the xml and java code? Maybe you have set an alpha value for the icons != 100%

Comment: Where is the xml for the options menu?

Comment: @JaredBurrows added that too.

Answer (score 1):

In your **`styles.xml`** add the following attributes to the style to hide the default ActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I've tried this and the failed to get different results.